# Using braces to label parts of an equation

Tags: equations, braces

Given an equation, say Bayes' rule,

```
$P(X \mid O) \propto P(X)P(O \mid X)$
```

how do I label the different parts of the equation using curly braces?

Comment: Ah braces, that what they're called. A Google search to "latex moustache" didn't lead me to `\overbrace`

Comment: @Paul: Your comment will help the next person.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I think you're after the `\underbrace` and `\overbrace` commands, which you could use as

```
$\underbrace{P(X \mid O)}_{p_1} \propto \overbrace{P(X)P(O \mid X)}^{p_2}$.
```

Which results in:

[image: Under- and overbraces]

Comment: I wonder why does adding underbrace/overbrace affect the font size?

Comment: Is it possible to move the under-/overbrace farther down/up?