# horizontal curly braces

Tags: underbrace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Using braces to label parts of an equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1588/using-braces-to-label-parts-of-an-equation)

How do I put horizontal curly braces beneath and over parts of a formula? I tried to use `\stackrel` and `\mathtop`, but it did not work.

Comment: I have found. I should use \overbrace{}^{} and \underbrace{}^{}.

Comment: Thanks for telling us that you found it! I closed it as a duplicate, since we had such a question already (several times).

Answer (score 98):

You can try the following commands:

```
\overbrace{your-formula}^\text{your comment} 
\underbrace{your-formula}_\text{your comment}
```

An example that I took from [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics):

```
\[
  z = \overbrace{
    \underbrace{x}_\text{real} +
    \underbrace{iy}_\text{imaginary}
   }^\text{complex number}
 \]
```

Their result:
[image: example showing the result of \underbrace{•} and \overbrace{•}]

Don't forget to add

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

at the beginning of your document

Comment: This doesn't really work for matrix