# How to change color of \underbrace{.}

Tags: beamer

I need to change the color of only underbrace in the following post.

[horizontal curly braces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46268/horizontal-curly-braces).

MWE from above link is:

```
\overbrace{your-formula}^\text{your comment} 
\underbrace{your-formula}_\text{your comment}
```

An example taken from [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics):

```
\[
  z = \overbrace{
    \underbrace{x}_\text{real} +
    \underbrace{iy}_\text{imaginary}
   }^\text{complex number}
 \]
```

Their result:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Package `color` helps. The range of the color is limited by TeX groups. Curly braces have a side effect of creating a sub formula in math mode, which affects the horizontal spacing, therefore `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` is used without that side effect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
    z = \overbrace{
    \begingroup
      \color{red}
      \underbrace{\color{black}x}_\text{\color{black}real}
    \endgroup
    +
    \begingroup
      \color{blue}
      \underbrace{\color{black}iy}_\text{\color{black}imaginary}
    \endgroup
   }^\text{complex number}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Wouldn't `\textcolor` instead of `\color` as in `\[
    z = \overbrace{
      \textcolor{red}{\underbrace{\color{black}x}_\text{\color{black}real}}
    +
      \textcolor{blue}{\underbrace{\color{black}iy}_\text{\color{black}imaginary}}
   }^\text{complex number}
\]` be simpler?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina `\textcolor` uses curly braces and therefore it becomes a subformula. Therefore it only can be used to color ordinary math atoms. In this example it would work, but it will not, when coloring the binary plus sign or the equals sign.

Comment: For small items,  `\underbracket` (from `mathtools`) would look nicer than `\underbrace`, in my opinion.